# AJAX JSON API, undefined and [object object] issues

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to create an API hence some of the information being removed, such as Bearer token. This is the first API I have attempted to write and I am struggling. Reading books and looking at examples online isn't helping so I hoped someone could explain where I am going wrong?

The reference to #Code is just an HTML input and #AJAXresponse is an article ID tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Code").keyup(function userInput() {
    console.log("Button Clicked");

    var input = $('#Code').val();

    var connect = {
      "url": "URL" + input,
      "method": "GET",
      "dataType": "json",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      }
    };

    //responded data
    $.ajax(connect).done(function(response) {
      var data;
      data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
      //console.log(response);
      console.log("Response should start here " + data);

      $('#AJAXresponse').html('<ul>' + data + '</ul>');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try to console log the response *before* you try to parse it, to see what it is.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Taplar I have tried consoling at different several different points. I get the [object object] output. I tried parsing which didn’t work. I am keen to try Barmar idea

Comment: So don't try to parse it.  It's already parsed, for the reason Barmar explained below.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `dataType: "json"`, jQuery automatically parses the response for you, and puts that result in the argument to the `.done()` function. There's no `responseText` property there, and you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`. So it should be:

```
$.ajax(connect).done(function(data) {
  console.log("Response should start here " + data);
  $('#AJAXresponse').html('<ul>' + data + '</ul>');
});
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for the help. I have made the suggested amendments and am getting an ouput of [object object] between the ul tags. What can you suggest?

Comment: figured it out, needed (JSON.stringify(data. ))

Comment: If you want to display the original JSON, just don't specify `dataType: "json"`. Then you don't need to parse it or stringify it.

Comment: But why would you want to show JSON in your application instead of extracting information from it?

Comment: Initially I wanted a full reply so I could be sure the API is working correctly. I am totally new at this so any help or advice is hugely appreciated. Now I've got the response, I have:         
$.each(data, function(key, value){                 
    var nlc_code = data.nlc_code;                         
         if (key === 'nlc_code') {
      $('AJAXresponse ul').append('<li>' + key + ' : ' + value + '</li>');
 }                                                                                                                    });

Comment: Looks good, except you forgot the `#` in `$("#AJAXresponse")`